# What is the purpose of numpy masked array in this function?

Tags: python, numpy

My code

```
def to_norm(self, x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ma.MaskedArray):
        data = x.filled()
        mask = x.mask
    else:
        data = x
        mask = None
```

As I understand `isinstance` is checking type.The appropriate array elements are going to be filled. But what about masking, how does it works and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.ma.MaskedArray` is a subclass of the regular numpy `ndarray`.  You can read all about in the docs.

This method apparently tries to handle argument `x` is consistent manner, regardless of whether it is `ndarray` or `MaskedArray`.

A masked array has a `data` attribute and `mask` attribute.  `x.filled()` returns the `data` with the masked values filled with the `x.fill_value`.

A masked array is used when you don't want to use some of the values of an array, for example if they are `np.nan` or some integer equivalent.  `x.filled` is one way of using that data with the 'bad values' replaced with something useful or innocuous.

My description will make a lot more sense if you read the `MaskedArray` docs.